# Why is this element outside the table?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to place something between two table rows, but the `something` row is outside the table in chrome browser:

[image]

I'm not sure why, it seems unless the `something` is inside a `td` tag, it would always be outside the table.

Why is that? I just want some row that can occupy the whole line, which is why I abandoned the `td` tag here.

Here's the source code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            td { border: 1px solid #666; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Header</th>
                    <th>Header</th>
                    <th>Header</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tr>
                <td>Data</td>
                <td>Data</td>
                <td>Data</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                something
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Data</td>
                <td>Data</td>
                <td>Data</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe because your markup is invalid? You can't just place something between rows, but rows.

Comment: @MelanciaUK not even `<tr>xx</tr>`? That is a `row`, right?

Comment: I didn't notice the opening/closing `tr` tags there. My bad.

Comment: you can put your 'somewhere' in a <td colspan=3> tag

Comment: It's still invalid; the only valid child of a `<tr>` is either `<td>` or `<th>`. Nothing else. At all. Wrap 'something' in either of those elements (ideally with an appropriate `colspan` attribute-value) and it'll work fine.

Comment: @DavidThomas it's been a long time since I used `tables`, so I was double checking. You're right (and so was I).

Comment: If you look at the created DOM with your browser's dev tools, you'll see that the `<tr>` will be empty and `something` will be a node outside of the table. The browser tries to make the best of a bad situation (invalid HTML).

Comment: That's the documentation: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/tr.html#tr

Comment: Any content you want to display as a table must be placed inside the <td> or <th> tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you wrote the text inside `<tr>` directly is not a valid HTML and result will be broken layout. If you are using table then use `<td>` to write a content.  As per posted table structure case as every `<tr>` contains 3 `<td>`.

So you need to write it this way. Then only you will get a proper table layout.

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="3">something</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 6):

I don't think you can do that. Instead set colspan="3" to the cell in that row. You can read more here: http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/tables/index_famsupp_30.html.

I.e.:

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="3">something</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't set something between rows, but rows. `<tr>` is a row, you're right. But a row must have columns to be a valid row.

This should be right:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            td { border: 1px solid #666; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Header</th>
                    <th>Header</th>
                    <th>Header</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tr>
                <td>Data</td>
                <td>Data</td>
                <td>Data</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3">Something</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Data</td>
                <td>Data</td>
                <td>Data</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```